# Python3 - Performance Issues when creating array of dictionaries from

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, lambda, python-3.6

I have three 1-d arrays (for example: x, y, z) which I am converting into an array of dictionaries (all three arrays are of the same length). The conversion is done using a combination of `map` and a `lambda` function:

```
res = numpy.array(list(map(lambda i: {'x': x[i], 'y':y[i], 'z': z[i]}, xrange(len(x)))))
```

The conversion takes way too long to complete. Is there a more efficient way to create the list/array of dictionaries?

Comment: Are you *really* sure you want an array of dicts, rather than some pure-`numpy` structure?

Comment: @Blckknght the array of dictionaries is an input to another method (not one that I wrote) which expects that kind of structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `ziping` them:

```
res = numpy.array([{'x': _x, 'y': _y, 'z': _z} for _x, _y, _z in zip(x,y,z)])
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/K7P5/2)